# Oneg Shabbos or Havadlah

Tags: grapes-wine, priorities, havdalah, oneg-shabbat

If one only has a limited income and has a choice between Oneg Shabbos or Wine for Havadlah which goes first?

Comment: A cup of grape juice for Havdala costs about $.30 nowadays. What kind of case is this?

Comment: Where it isn't 30 cents...(:

Comment: A dollar? Whose Oneg Shabbos is dependent on that sum of money?

Comment: @DoubleAA Many poor people! Learn some Gemorah!

Comment: And there's no shul nearby? What gemara are you referring to?

Comment: The Gemorah tells us of poor who didn't have money to buy wine, they had to sell their clothes!

Comment: You can just admit this is basically a hypothetical question...

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara [Pesachim 113a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=113&format=text) says

> אמר רבי יוחנן שלשה מנוחלי העוה"ב אלו הן הדר בא"י והמגדל בניו לתלמוד תורה והמבדיל על היין במוצאי שבתות מאי היא דמשייר מקידושא לאבדלתא

And the Rashbam writes:

> דמשייר מקידושא. שיש לו מעט יין ומונע שתייתו בשביל הבדלה

Rabbi Yochanan said that if saves what little wine he has for Havdalah, he inherits the world-to-come.

Obviously, Havdala overrides Oneg Shabbos

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the Kal VaChomer. Do you know what the reward is for having Oneg Shabbos? Is comparing Aggadic statements of reward a valid means for a Halakhic Kal VaChomer?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't see a _kal vachomer_. _Rashbam_ or whoever that second quotation is from (dunno who and the answer should indicate) says that the person is minimizing _Shabas_ drinking to _havdel al hakos_, precisely the case asked about in our question, and indicates that such a person is rewarded, which thus answers our question.